# powershell: get-winevent has no message data?

Tags: powershell, event-log, event-viewer

When I run the script below to retrieve log files, the get-winevent "message" field is blank, but has data if I run get-eventlog. Any ideas why?

```
#has message data 
Get-Eventlog -LogName application -Newest 10

 #date 10 days ago 
$EventStartDate = get-date("10 May 2012") 
$EventEndDate = get-date("11 May 2012") 
$EventLogNames = @("Application", "system")

#critea for winevent 
$EventCritea = @{logname = $EventLogNames; StartTime=$EventStartDate; EndTime=$EventEndDate}

#Retrieves the event log 
$RetreivedEvents = Get-WinEvent -computername localhost -FilterHashtable $EventCritea
$RetreivedEvents | fl id, logname, MachineName, Message, TimeCreated
```

Comment: Just wondering -- have you tried this on a different system? Both work on mine.

Comment: Did message contain data? Ive tried it on 2 windows 7 clients.  Which os version did you try it on?

Comment: It looks like its a operating system specific because windows 2008 R2 displays the the results with message but windows 7 does not

Comment: I've seen this error on my Windows 8 machine (using PowerShell v3) looking at local event logs, for almost all results. Running your code results in the same for me (the majority of messages being empty but some visible). 

Starting PowerShell with the "-version 2" switch seems to resolve the issue but obviously Windows 7 is v2 by default, which is odd! Culture is en-GB.

Comment: It's an active bug on Microsoft Connect. [Get-WinEvent does not return the content of the Event Message in V3 CTP2](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/716533/get-winevent-does-not-return-the-content-of-the-event-message-in-v3-ctp2). Vote for it to persuade Microsoft to fix this.

Answer (score 8):

What locale are you running under?

There is a .NET bug where the underlying .NET method (that `Get-WinEvent` uses) fails to populate localised fields (like `Message`) in some locales (like `en-GB`).

Fix is to switch to `en-US` for the command:

```
$orgCulture = Get-Culture
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New-Object "System.Globalization.CultureInfo" "en-US"
# Perform Get-WinEvent
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $orgCulture
```

Comment: This fix will probably only work intermittently given that PowerShell will sometimes execute different commands on different threads.

Comment: @JasonStangroome In a script everything is processed on a single thread, the creation of lots of threads seems to be a function of the command line (I have this working via a wrapper replacement for `Get-WinEvent`).

Comment: There is a Microsoft Connect item about this issue. [Get-WinEvent does not return the content of the Event Message in V3 CTP2](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/716533/get-winevent-does-not-return-the-content-of-the-event-message-in-v3-ctp2). Vote for it to persuade Microsoft to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because the messages are hidden in a property value. To display all messages, pipe the get-winevent to the select statement with the following expressions:

```
@{Label='Messages';Expression={$_.properties.Value}}
```

If you wish to display a specific message, for instance Logon Process (In security logs), use the expression:

```
@{Label='Logon Process';Expression={$_.properties.Value[3]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I have seen get-winevent not work on Windows Server 2003 in the past when I have tried it.  Basically the PS environment said get-winevent didn't work for 2003.  That may have been PS v1 then, so I am not sure if that was resolved with newer versions of PS:  I am on 2K8 R2 now.

On my

Comment: It looks like its a operating system specific because windows 2008 R2 displays the the results with message but windows 7 does not.

Answer (score 0):

What PSHost are you running under?

I am experiencing a problem on PS V2.0 running on windows 7 accessing W2k8. If run within a Powershell console or within Powershell ISE it retrieves all data. However if running within a runspace or from PowerGUI (pro) it returns only a partial subset which does not include the Message property.

[EDIT]
Richard's post allows me to work around the problem but it is very strange because the culture in the working PS console is 'en-GB' and the culture in the non working PowerGui Script Editor is 'en-GB' which only works if I change the culture to 'en-US'.

Freaky

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line at the top of my script worked for me (taken from Richards code Snippet) ;

```
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New-Object "System.Globalization.CultureInfo" "en-US"
```

Answer (score 0):

[PS 2.0] Note that a culture change is only valid for the current pipeline.
See [Culture Gotchas](http://www.xipher.dk/WordPress/?p=706)

So the command to temporarily change culture + get-winevent need to be grouped either in a script block (enclosed within "{...}") or on one line separated by ";".

I discovered this when trying to use get-winevent on system log on Server 2008. Messages came up empty, and I needed to change the culture from nl-BE to en-US.